# alinhamento de div e resumir texto

Tags: css

- 1 Preciso colocar tudo dentro da div 'container-head' alinhado na horizontal.
- 2 O texto da div 'c-txt' tem que ser resumido com ...
- 3 O botão da div 'c-bt' tem que ficar com o tamanha mínimo de 100px.

Alguém pode me ajudar? segue o código.

```css
.container {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
  width: 95%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
}
.container table {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.container .linha {
  border-top: 1px solid #D7D7D7;
}
.container-head {
  width: 100%;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  height: 65px;
  background: #000;
  line-height: 65px;
}
.container-head .c-ico {
  float: left;
  width: 10%;
}
.container-head .c-txt {
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.container-head .c-bt {
  width: 20%;
  min-width: 120px;
  float: right;
}
.container-head .c-bt button {
  border: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 42px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<!-- Material Icons (Google) -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">

  <!-- Container Head -->
  <div class="container-head">
    <div class="c-ico"><i class="material-icons ">grade</i>
    </div>
    <div class="c-txt">TÍTULO GRANDE TEM QUE FICAR RESUMIDO POR ...</div>
    <div class="c-bt">
      <button type='submit'>FINALIZAR</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Dá uma olhada nessa resposta talvez lhe ajude: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/153211/como-posso-fazer-que-em-determinada-classe-apare%C3%A7a-ap%C3%B3s-atingir-um-limite/153214#153214

Comment: não me ajudou, preciso alinhar essas div, o resumo já esta sendo feito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizei a propriedade `flex` para alinhar o conteúdo, veja como ficou...

```css
.container {
  margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
}
.container-head {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  height: 65px;
  background: #000;
  line-height: 65px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.container-head * {
  margin: 0 5px;
}
.container-head .c-txt {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.container-head .c-txt::after {
  content: '...';
}
.container-head .c-bt button {
  border: 0;
  height: 42px;
  min-width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
<div class="container">
  <!-- Container Head -->
  <div class="container-head">
    <div class="c-ico"><i class="material-icons ">grade</i>
    </div>
    <div class="c-txt"
      <span class="text">TÍTULO GRANDE TEM QUE FICAR RESUMIDO POR</span>
    </div>
    <div class="c-bt">
      <button type='submit'>FINALIZAR</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tipo assim:

```css
.container {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
  width: 95%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
}
.container table {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.container .linha {
  border-top: 1px solid #D7D7D7;
}
.container-head {
  width: 100%;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  height: 65px;
  background: #000;
  line-height: 65px;
}
.container-head .c-ico i{
  float: left;
  line-height: 65px;
  margin-right:5px;
  margin-left:5px;
}
.container-head .c-txt {
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.container-head .c-bt {
  width: 20%;
  min-width: 120px;
  float: right;
}
.container-head .c-bt button {
  border: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 42px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<!-- Material Icons (Google) -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">

  <!-- Container Head -->
  <div class="container-head">
    <div class="c-ico"><i class="material-icons ">grade</i>
    </div>
    <div class="c-txt">TÍTULO GRANDE TEM QUE FICAR RESUMIDO POR ...         </div>
    <div class="c-bt">
      <button type='submit'>FINALIZAR</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```